# How does ConcurrentHashMap resizeStamp method work?

Tags: java, concurrency

In the source code of `ConcurrentHashMap`, there is a method called `resizeStamp`, the code is:

```
static final int resizeStamp(int n) {
    return Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n) | (1 << (RESIZE_STAMP_BITS - 1));
}
```

How does this code work?

Comment: What don't you understand about it, specifically? It's fairly obvious what the method itself does, more interesting question is "what is its purpose?"

Comment: what is its purpose

Answer (score 3):

> Short Answer: take `sc` as the result of `(resizeStamp(n) << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT)`, the higher 16 bit of `sc` tells the information that there are at least one thread doing resizing operation on capcity `n`， the lower 16 bit tells the information that how many theards are doing this resizing concurrently.

**Explaination:**

First, checkout the documentation of `resizeStamp(n)`

```
/**
 * Returns the stamp bits for resizing a table of size n.
 * Must be negative when shifted left by RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT.
 */
static final int resizeStamp(int n) {
    return Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n) | (1 << (RESIZE_STAMP_BITS - 1));
}
```

so this function clearly do two things

1. compute leading zero numbers of n as `tmpReuslt`
2. make the 16th bit of `tmpResult` be 1 ( Notice: `RESIZE_STAMP_BITS` is a constant which equals 16 )

so resizeStamp return a 32-bit int value which has format `0000 0000 0000 0000 1xxx xxx xxxx xxxx`

as the documentation says, the return result " Must be negative when shifted left by RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT" .

Obviously, when the 16th bit is set to 1, when shifted left by   RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT , the highest bit of the reuslt would be 1, which make it a negative number.

Then, the second question comes, why does it do this, checkout the `addCount(long x, int check)` function in ConcurrentHashMap

```
 // some code here
 if (check >= 0) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab, nt; int n, sc;
        while (s >= (long)(sc = sizeCtl) && (tab = table) != null &&
               (n = tab.length) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            int rs = resizeStamp(n);
            if (sc < 0) {
                if ((sc >>> RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) != rs || sc == rs + 1 ||
                    sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || (nt = nextTable) == null ||
                    transferIndex <= 0)
                    break;
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                    transfer(tab, nt);
            }
            else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,
                                         (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2))
                transfer(tab, null);
            s = sumCount();
        }
    }
```

resizeStamp is used to assgin value of sizeCtl in ConcurrentHashMap, by operation `(rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2`.

resizeStamp function ensures `sizeCtl` gets a negative value if

```
U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,(rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2)
```

executed successfully.

- And the higher 16 bit of `sizeCtl` can tell the information : on which size `n`, the resizing operation is going on